# In .net core 2.0 set different session timeout for different roles

Tags: session-timeout, .net-core-2.0

Set session timeout as 45 days for role with user and default session timeout for admin user.Is it possible to set different session timeout for different roles?

I have integrated nuget package of session in .net core 2.0 and the code written in  configure method is as below

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
                {
                    Path = "/",
                    Name = "ABC",
                    Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(36000)
                };
                // options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
                // options.CookieName = "ASP.NetCoreSession";
                //options.CookiePath = "/";
            });
```

Currently I Have set timeout in hours

Comment: you should provide more detials and explain well your problem. If you have code to share, you should do it. your question is not clear enough

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori please do see the edits I made in my question.Hope now its clear